# Reading software version numbers(glibc-2.3.4-2.43)

Tags: linux, centos, glibc

I am releaseing an application to a client. I created executable in Ubuntu machine and it has higher version of glibc and client has lower version of glibc. So its giving me glibc conflict. So I am trying to create a machine with lower version of glibc(centos 4).

I have cent os 4.0 and centos 4.8 images? So which centos version should I go with?

I need glibc-2.3.4-2.36, But in cent os 4.8 it is mentioning it has glibc-2.3.4-2.43.

1. Are they two different versions of glibc?
2. How to read the glibc version numbers(I mean what is 2.36 or 2.43 stands for in glibc version)?
   3.What version of glibc does centos 4.0 have?

Comment: Either ship source code and compile on client system, or install (perhaps in a VM or a `chroot`-ed environment) your client's Linux distribution.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : Client has RHEL 4.5. which has glibc-2.3.4-2.36. And centos 4.8 has glibc-2.3.4-2.43. So will it work if i create the executable in centos 4.8? there is only  glibc conflict i think! where can i get how glibc are following the version numbers?

Comment: you can get iso of CentOS 4.5 here, http://vault.centos.org/4.5/isos/i386/ which should have the same version of glibc with your client. However I would recommend using static link in your case since the OS version of client is too old, and also you don't have the same environment with the client.